# SNS implementtion of IOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Im trying to create an application using AWS SDK with the following code.

```
$AmazonSNS->createPlatformApplication(array(
    'Name'=>"GameplandevApns",
    'Platform'=>'APNS',
    'Attributes'=>array(                       
        'PlatformPrincipal'=>'safdafafsafasasafdafa',
        'PlatformCredential'=>'asfdafdsadfsafasfsasa'   
    )                       
));
```

I am getting the error:

> Invalid parameter: PlatformPrincipal not valid.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same implementation, and I have a doubt, in the PlatformPrincipal, we have to use the private_key as string or the file pem reference?

Answer (score 2):

For APNS, the PlatformPrincipal is used for the SSL certificate from Apple while the PlatformCredential is the private key. Here is the [Getting Started Guide for APNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html) and the [Create Platform Application API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformApplication.html).